# Visual Studio 2005, posso substituir?

Tags: visual-studio

Tenho uma maquina na empresa que tem uma versão do Visual Studio 2005, para um tipo de sistema web.

A máquina precisou passar por uma formatação e na rede não a uma cópia VS2005.

Posso substituir o Visual Studio 2005 por alguma versão, talvez o Visual Studio Community?

Minha preocupação geral é com relação a algum tipo de incompatibilidade

Answer (score 3):

As versões do Visual Studio 2002, 2003, 2005 e 2008 geram projetos independentes, ou seja quando você abre na versão mais avançada ele converte para a nova versão. A partir da versão 2010, os projetos são compátiveis, você pode abrir no 2012 e depois abrir no 2010 e assim por diante.

Quanto ao framework .Net ele vai manter a compatibilidade com o projeto, porém alguns componentes terão que ser atualizados como o ReportServer e CrystalReports, e outros se você estiver usando.

Sim, você pode substituir, terá que fazer pequenas adaptações, mas nada muito trabalhoso.

Recomendo fazer uma cópia antes caso precise ou deseje voltar.

Comment: Obrigado, vou analisar para tomar esse rumo.

Answer (score 3):

Existe alguma incompatibilidade, mas é pequena, certamente terá que fazer algumas adaptações, tem até conversor nele para os arquivos de projeto que mudaram (acho que roda automático).

Agora, muita coisa não é bem incompatibilidade, é jeito diferente de fazer. Como está acostumado com uma coisa, a mudança pode assustar, pode parecer que tem problemas e na verdade é só falta de conhecimento. Você terá que decidir se começa usar versões mais recentes do compilador e .Net, o que aconselho fortemente, ou se vai configurar tudo para trabalhar com versões antigas.

Algumas coisas que ossa ter feito no projeto pode ser mais incompatível que outras, mas duvido que encontre grandes problemas, é raro alguém fazer algo muito diferente. Claro que pode ser seu caso.

Extensões do VS podem não ser compatíveis, pode ter que pegar uma versão mais nova ou não existir uma versão nova compatível.

Eu poderia lhe dizer que ficar no 2005 é mais seguro, mas na prática é o posto, ficar com um software tão antigo e até onde sei não mais suportado é que não é seguro. Vá para o 2015 já e pague o preço de ter que adaptar. Se tivesse feito as atualizações ao longo do tempo seria menos traumático. Mas não espere nada trágico. Você deve ser um desenvolvedor, então deve achar soluções. Se tiver dificuldades específicas poste aqui.

Não é algo que é só instalar e vai funcionar, mas é perfeitamente factível. Na pior das hipóteses se não der certo mesmo você poderia tentar voltar para o VS 2005, o que não aconselho de forma alguma.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. A questão de não atualizar com o tempo, não foi viável, por que eu ingressei em uma empresa a pouco tempo, e isso já tem anos, queria migrar para versão mais recente justamente por isso.

Comment: @Marzine dê uma olhada no [tour] e entenda a melhor forma de dizer obrigado. Você pode aceitar uma só resposta em pergunta que fez. Marque quando achar que deve a que mais lhe ajudou. Você pode votar em tudo no site que achar útil, não só aqui.